# Widget update by AlarmManager, onUpdate() keeps being called

Tags: android, android-widget

I've followed the tutorial on widget at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html, and I also know how to create an AlarmManager to update the widget. What I'm wondering is how to effectively turn off the default onUpdate(). According to the guide lines (at that link), when I use AlarmManager I should set `updatePeriodMillis` to zero. But `onUpdate()` keeps being called (because 0 always lapses). If I set it to, say, 30 mins, it updates at that period. So practically it keeps using the value in `updatePeriodMillis`  , which nullifies the effect of using AlarmManager. Am I missing anything?

**Update:** actually there's another code that triggers the update on another event, so never mind.
Cheers.

Comment: Could you post the code? You probably did something wrong since updatePeriod set to zero definitely shuts down the onUpdate() method...it only gets called the first time you place your widget.

Comment: can u post ur widget class onUpdate and onReceive the code

Comment: Thanks guys, I've found the bug.